# REGEX: How to match string that followed by space and contains specific char/symbol

Tags: php, regex

i have the following string

```
string string#string#string string
string$string (string) string string string
string string#gulaen#string string-stringan 
(string) string#string#string$string string string (string)
string string string$string#string$string#string string
string string#string$string#string string
string#string$string#string string
```

with this pattern `/\b(\w+[\#\$])\w+\b/` i try to match string that followed by space and contains # and $ but i can't get the result that i want. i get the folowing result

[image]

what i expect is to match the following highlighted blue:

[image]

how to achieve that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a group that will match the special symbol and 1+ word chars, and quantify it with `+`:

```
/\b\w+(?:[#$]\w+)+\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qf3pYb/1)

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:[#$]\w+)+` - a non-capturing group that matches 1 or more consecutive occurrences of a `#` or `$` chars followed with 1+ word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/StirWS):

```
echo preg_replace('/\b\w+(?:[#$]\w+)+\b/u', '<span>$0</span>', $str);
```

Output for the `$str` in question:

```
string <span>string#string#string</span> string
<span>string$string</span> (string) string string string
string <span>string#gulaen#string</span> string-stringan 
(string) <span>string#string#string$string</span> string string (string)
string string <span>string$string#string$string#string</span> string
string <span>string#string$string#string</span> string
<span>string#string$string#string</span> string
```

[Matching code demo](https://ideone.com/CGkyaU):

```
if (preg_match_all('/\b\w+(?:[#$]\w+)+\b/u', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string#string#string
    [1] => string$string
    [2] => string#gulaen#string
    [3] => string#string#string$string
    [4] => string$string#string$string#string
    [5] => string#string$string#string
    [6] => string#string$string#string
)
```